# Why am I getting this compile error?

Tags: java

I need to preface this with I am not allowed to use an IDE in class, I must use TextPad to compile and run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There are two files at play here, one called Account and the other called Lab4B. The assignment is to create and use the following files:
Lab4B.java = source code for the driver code class (Lab4B) for the assignments 
Account.java = source code for the Account class

The instructions are:
Design a class named Account (that contains

1. A private int data field named id for the account (default 0).
2. A private double data field named balance for the account (default 0).
3. A private double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current          interest rate (default 0).  Assume all accounts have the same interest rate.
4. A private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when the account was created.
5. A no-arg constructor that creates a default account.
6. A constructor that creates an account with the specified id and initial balance.
7. The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
8. The accessor method for dateCreated.
9. A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
10. A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.
11. A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount from the account.

**I am getting the following errors:**
The errors are when I compile the "Lab4B" file.

```
F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
   ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B

F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
2 errors
```

**The code for "Account" is below:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class Account
{

    int id = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    double annualInterestRate = 0;
    Date dateCreated;


    public Account()
    {

    }

    public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate)
    {

    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    this.dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    public void setID (int id)
    {
    this.id = id;
    }


    public int getID()
    {
    return this.id;
    }


    public void setBalance (double balance)
    {
    this.balance = balance;
    }


    public double getbalance()
    {
    return this.balance;
    }


    public void setAnnualInterestrate (double annualInterestRate)
    {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }


    public double getAnnualInterestrate()
    {
    return this.annualInterestRate;
    }


    public Date getDateCreated()
    {
    return this.dateCreated;
    }


    public double getMonthlyInterestRate()
    {
    return (this.annualInterestRate) / 12;
    }


    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
    this.balance -= amount;
    System.out.println ("After withdrawing $"+amount +" the balance in your account is:                                                  $   " +this.balance +"\n");
    }


public void deposit(double amount)
{
    this.balance += amount;
    System.out.println(" After making a deposit of $"+amount +" the balance in your    account is: $"  +this.balance + "\n");
}
 }
```

**The code for the Lab4B file is below:**

```
public class Lab4B
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

   // Creates an instance of Account

   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);

   // Sets default amounts

   account.setID(5544);
   account.setBalance(45000);
   account.setAnnualInterestRate(0.036);
   account.withdraw(3700);
   account.deposit(2200);

   // Prints output

   System.out.println ("Account number: \n"+ +account.getID());
   System.out.println ("The account balance is: $ \n" + +account.getbalance());
   System.out.println ("The monthly interest earned is: $ \n" + +account.getbalance() *    account.annualInterestRate());
   System.out.println ("The account was created on: \n" + +account.getdateCreated());
 }
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting from the javac command line compiler as suggested:

```
C:\>javac Lab4B.java
Lab4B.java:5: error: package mypackage does not exist
import mypackage.Account;
                ^
Lab4B.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
   ^
   symbol:   class Account
   location: class Lab4B
Lab4B.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
3 errors
```

Here is the javac -verbose output:

```
C:\Users\kschultz>cd\

C:\>javac -verbose Lab4B.java
[parsing started RegularFileObject[Lab4B.java]]
[parsing completed 12ms]
[search path for source files: .C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib,C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\re
sources.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jd
k1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jce.j
ar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\classes,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\
 lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\localedata
 .jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Fi
 les (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files (x86
 )\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.
 0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\e
 xt\zipfs.jar,.C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib,C:\Program Files (x86)
\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
[checking Lab4B]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/AutoCloseable.class)]]
Lab4B.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
    ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
 Lab4B.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
                          ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
 [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
 ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/System.class)]]
 [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
 ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/PrintStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FilterOutputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.s
ym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/OutputStream.class)]]
[total 228ms]
2 errors
```

Comment: What's the command line you're using to compile? Is `Lab4B.java` in the same directory as `Account.java`? Can you show a directory listing of `F:\Java\Lab 4b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your errors are related to the same problem.

```
Lab4B.java:5: error: package mypackage does not exist
Lab4B.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
```

**Problem**:

- Your Account class doesn't contain package declaration. (check if Account class is really inside a "mypackage" directory)
- Your Lab4B class doesn't contain a package import.

**Solution**:

Package declaration syntax

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
public class Account {
   //rest of the code
```

The statement order is as follows.

1. Package statment (optional).
2. Imports (optional).
3. Class or interface definitions.

Package Import syntax

```
import mypackage.Account;
public class Lab4B
{
   //rest of code
```

There are 3 ways you can specify package imports.

The JOptionPane class is in the swing package, which is located in the javax package. The wildcard character (*) is used to specify that all classes with that package are available to your program. This is the most common programming style.

```
import javax.swing.*;  // Make all classes visible altho only one is used.

class ImportTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Classes can be specified explicitly on import instead of using the wildcard character.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  // Make a single class visible.

class ImportTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Alternately we can the fully qualified class name without an import.

```
class ImportTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You can read more about packages [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 1):

When the Java compiler compiles Lab4B.java, it will want to be able to find (or compile) the `Account` class.  The compiler is saying that it wasn't able to find the `Account` class.

A couple possibilities for this problem:

- "Account.java" isn't in the same directory as "Lab4B.java" - note that the name is case-sensitive.  If the file is named "account.java", the compiler will not find the `Account` class.
- "Account.java" isn't supposed to be in the same directory as "Lab4B.java" - if that's the case, it's in a different package. You'll either need to `import` the package where the `Account` class can be found, or you need to specify the full package name when referring to the `Account` class in the `Lab4B` class.  You'll also need to make sure the `CLASSPATH` is configured correctly if appropriate.

---

Update based on the compiler's `-verbose` output:

The problem looks like it's because something is setting the Java compiler's sourcepath to an incorrect value:

```
[search path for source files: .C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip]
```

The problem is that the current directory isn't in the search path (the `.` has been concatenated with another path without a separator). It looks like you have a bad `CLASSPATH` environment variable that doesn't have a semi-colon after the `.` part of the classpath configuration.

Fix that and the compiler should be able to find `Account.java`. Then you'll get a few compiler errors due to typos in the source files that should be straightforward to fix.

Comment: Here is the path, F:\Java\Lab 4b. They are both in the same directory.  F:\Java\Lab 4b\Account.java & F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java.                              The classpath is as follows:  .C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip                                 The system variable path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\;;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Netop\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;

Comment: It looks like `javac` should be able to find `Account.java`, so I'm not sure what's going on.  Try `javac -verbose Lab4B.java` and post the output to the bottom of your question.

Comment: The files are in the same directory, and @Michael Burr I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Kevin: if you run the Java compiler using the command line: `javac -verbose Lab4B.java`,  it'll spit out several lines of diagnostics that may shed light on the problem.  Use the clipboard to copy those lines to your question (use the "edit" link that's under the `[java]` and `[homework]` tag buttons).

Comment: @Kevin: sorry for the back-n-forth, but the `-verbose` option is missing from the command line. And you should remove the `import mypackage.Account;` line since you apparently shouldn't need to import a package. Even if you do need to import a package, it'll almost certainly have a different name than `mypackage`.

Comment: @Kevin: your CLASSPATH isn't right - please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `Account` class in your `Lab4B` class. Something along the lines:

```
import mypackage.Account;
```

Put this at the top of the `Lab4B` class, before any other code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I now have the following error in addition to the original ones.  F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java:5: error: package mypackage does not exist
import mypackage.Account;
                ^
F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
   ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
F:\Java\Lab 4b\Lab4B.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   Account account = new Account(5544, 45000, 0.036);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class Lab4B
3 errors